# Can lights be reused in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it mandatory to specify three JS lights every time a 3d model is loaded?

When rendering is done on software's like Maya, there is a light and camera config that is done. Is there a way to export that as a part of OBJ file? If we can reuse the same light config, then the code can be generic for every 3d model or is there a default light config that will work for 90% of the 3d models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to export that as a part of OBJ file?

No since OBJ does not supports lights and cameras. However, other formats like glTF do.

> If we can reuse the same light config, then the code can be generic for every 3d model or is there a default light config that will work for 90% of the 3d models?

It depends on the materials in your scene what lighting setup makes sense. E.g. in a scene with PBR materials, you definitely want to use a HDR environment map for image based lighting. A more simple scene with a lambert material does not require such a setup (so an ambient in combination with a point or directional light is sufficient).

Comment: Is there a reference link where I can read up on the flexibility that glTF offers?

Comment: The official glTF homepage provides a ton of information about the 3D standard. I suggest you start from there: https://www.khronos.org/gltf/